# jQuery pause a while loop

Tags: jquery

I am trying to roll through my banner images using a while loop in jQuery.

I need to find a way to pause each cycle of the loop so the banner images can cycle round slowly.

Here is my code

```
var bannerIMG = ['img1','img2','img3'];
var counter = 0;
var num = 1;
while (num <= 3) {
$('#header').addClass(bannerIMG[counter]);
   counter = counter +1;    
   num = num+1;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show a fiddle?

Comment: A `setInterval` or `setTimeout` would be more appropriate

Comment: @roXon is right, or if you need more you can use deferred functions (see the jQuery Promise object) and a setTimeout that goes to the next function in the list.

Comment: http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/setinterval-example/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uresal/4/edit)**</kbd>

```
var img = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3'],
    c = 0,
    run = setInterval(loop, 1000); 

function loop(){ 
  $('#header').removeClass().addClass( img[++c%img.length] );    
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators/
http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: @GeorgeShikariReason You're welcome! well, I changed a bit my code since last time ;)

Answer (score -2):

Got it working with this code

```
var bannerIMG = ['img1','img2','img3'];
var counter = 0;
function loop(){
    $('#header').addClass(bannerIMG[counter]);
    counter = counter+1;
}

setInterval(loop, 1000);
```

Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: with +=1, it'll fail once it gets to the 4th image (since it doesn't exist in the array)